# iPad plugged to charger turns off due to low battery

Tags: ipad, battery, charging

My iPad is connected to charger yet battery level decreases (not as fast as plugged off but still).

Is it a fault that can be directed to Apple Support for warranty or normal behaviour? I though that charging by cable and using device means power is taken directly from grid while battery loads.

PS
It's charged by iPhone plug. iPad plug is bigger and I am in trip so took smaller one. Those end plugs give different charging capabilities? Is it safe to actually swap them like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An iPad needs twice the power of an iPhone to charge.

A phone charger will slowly be able to charge an iPad, but possibly not be able to keep up whilst it is in use & doing intensive tasks.

It's safe to swap them, an iPhone using an iPad charger will not be damaged, but as you see, the other way round, the iPad is not getting sufficient charge.

Even switched off, the iPad may show 'not charging' at the top right - but it actually will still be charging, just very slowly.

Comment: I've plugged it into battery ran MacBook and now its "overcharging" (charging more than consumes). How's USB port in laptop better than grid charger?

Comment: Macs have a special high-rated power output on the USB ports so that they can recognise & respond to an iPad's power requirement.

Answer (score 0):

What was mentioned above is true. The ipod and iphone uses 1.2 amps, and the ipads use 2 amps. I have run over the same problem tons of times, i Close all apps besides the one i'm using, BUT I have to reduce the brightness to half or less in my device to stay on. If it is at like 50% Brightness  my battery level will remain the same, it will not charge but at least it won't die on me. if i drop the brightness to 25% it will start charging but slower than usual while in use. and if i almost get it back to the lowest i can see it will charge ok.

Comment: It's some kind of joke for me. Why stupid USB cable charges better than relatively big charger of iPad?

Answer (score 0):

I just had issue twice once in July and just this month it charged to 77% and no more swap cables same swap charging USB same so used it till got down about 36% plug it in charge all night next morning 100%.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).